# Pandas: Two dataframes of different sizes but similar values. I need the data from df2 when df1 has similar values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with smaller intervals than another dataframe with other information I need.

Below is an example of the results that would be input

```
df1
  Labels  Interval
0     A1         1
1     A1         2
2     A1         3
3     A1         4
4     A2         1
5     A2         2
6     A2         3
7     A2         4

df2
  Labels  From  To  Data
0     A1     0   2   103
1     A1     2   4   110
2     A2     0   2   110
3     A2     2   4   103
```

I need to create the new column (Data) in dataframe df1 from df2

```
df1
  Labels  Interval  Data
0     A1         1   103
1     A1         2   103
2     A1         3   110
3     A1         4   110
4     A2         1   110
5     A2         2   110
6     A2         3   103
7     A2         4   103
```

I've tried using np.where and df.loc functions but because they are different sizes it's not really working. I'm trying to do a for loop now but the code is taking a long time for the entire dataset.

```
df1['Data'] =np.where((df1['Interval'] <= df2['To']) & (df1['Interval'] >= df2['From']) & (df1['Labels'] == df2['Labels']),df2['Data'],'NA')
```

Edit**

I should have also added that in this scenario the intervals and from/to items are are sequential but in the actual dataset there are 0.5 and increments which I think is making it difficult to map data, which is why I wanted to used the < and > functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a `IntervalIndex` from the columns `From` and `To`, then using `MultiIndex.map` map the `Data` from `df2` to `df1`

```
i = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['From'], df2['To'])
df1['Data'] = df1.set_index(['Labels', 'Interval']).index\
                 .map(df2.set_index(['Labels', i])['Data'])
```

---

```
  Labels  Interval  Data
0     A1         1   103
1     A1         2   103
2     A1         3   110
3     A1         4   110
4     A2         1   110
5     A2         2   110
6     A2         3   103
7     A2         4   103
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: 
InvalidIndexError: cannot handle overlapping indices; use IntervalIndex.get_indexer_non_unique

I updated the question and maybe it's due to the 0.5 intervals that are in my data set (as the one I provided was just an example). I'll keep working away at it though.

Comment: @Manks As the error suggests, you might have overlapping intervals in the `From` and `To` column for some `Labels` . You need to define some strategy to handle overlapping intervals. Is the solution working on the sample data you have provided in the original question?

Comment: Yeah it works on the orginal set I gave you. So I think I just have to play with it some more. Thanks!

Comment: Update, I put your code in a loop and it fixed the error, I'm assuming there was some sort of cross over values or something (there is over 2000 of the A1, A2, B19 with up to 250 intervals) putting the code into a loop using .unique on the Labels and using .loc to confine the data worked on getting rid of the error. Thanks again for you help the mapping function is nice and I'm glad I could learn something new today!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `.explode` `df2` on the interval From/To and then merge with `df1` (if the `Interval` column is integer):

```py
df2 = df2.assign(
    Interval=df2.apply(lambda x: range(x["From"] + 1, x["To"] + 1), 1)
).explode("Interval")

print(df1.merge(df2, on=["Labels", "Interval"])[[*df1.columns, "Data"]])
```

Prints:

```
  Labels Interval  Data
0     A1        1   103
1     A1        2   103
2     A1        3   110
3     A1        4   110
4     A2        1   110
5     A2        2   110
6     A2        3   103
7     A2        4   103
```